# How can I append the same element several times in python?

Tags: python, list, pyqt, append, qlineedit

I am creating a GUI with NUMBER of line edits. However, to get the text that is written in them I tried to make a list of LineEdits and append/add a LineEdit element to the list for each iteration. 
Then I tried to add the current item to the layout and when pushing continue be able to change the NAME_LIST to the rename lineEdits.

I have tried to written out the length of the self.lineEditRename and it seems as the same item cannot be appended several times. Is this right, and how can I get around this?
I get this error when I run the file..

```py
layout.addWidget(self.lineEditRename[i],2,i)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

please help:)

```py
# NAME LIST
self.NAME_LIST = []
for i in range(0, NUMBER):
    self.NAME_LIST.append("NUMBER: "+ str(i))

for i in range(0,NUMBER+1):
            print(i)
            if (i==0):
                layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Rename: "),2,i))
            else:
                layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.NAME_LIST[i-1]),0,i)
                self.lineEditRename = [QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self), QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)]
                self.lineEditRename.append(QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self))
                layout.addWidget(self.lineEditRename[i-1],2,i)

self.QContinueButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Continue")
self.QContinueButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.windowtwo(NUMBER))
layout.addWidget(self.QContinueButton,10,2)


def windowtwo(self, NUMBER):
        for i in range(1,NUMBER+1):
            print(self.lineEditRename[i].text())
            self.NAME_LIST[i-1]=self.lineEditRename[i].text()
        self.switch_window.emit()
```

Comment: Your error is coming from indexing your list with just `i`, you should instead index it with `i-1` when you are using an number range of `[1, N]` instead of `[0, N)`

Comment: Hmm thank you! It still does not work though..

Comment: @AuroraS please do not update your post with suggested answers. Your question should stay the same.

Comment: @AuroraS you are still indexing with `i` in the `windowtwo` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because of this line `self.lineEditRename = [QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self), QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)]`. The length of `self.lineEditRename` will always be 3 so as soon as `i` becomes 3, you will get a `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Did you mean to do this instead:

```
self.lineEditRename = [QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self), QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)]
for i in range(0,NUMBER+1):
    print(i)
    if (i==0):
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Rename: "),2,i))
    else:
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.NAME_LIST[i-1]),0,i)
        self.lineEditRename.append(QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self))
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEditRename[i],2,i)
```